# my websocket is not working after i have deployed my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

so i have my frontend in react and backened in nodejs.I have deployed my backened and frontened both on vercel.
locally the application is running very well . i am replacing the server deployed link with my endpoint in the frontend.
MY Problem:
I am getting no messages on my application and getting multiple websockets after i got in inspect.

[its the server's log of vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PjRg.png)

further i have tried cors and i am providing my server code and frontened code both below.i am so in problems rn... please anyone help me
also please see this the frontend link after deployment
https://galactico-chat-app.vercel.app/
see the network tab too

if you can help me please also see this full code repo
https://github.com/vaibhav211002/chat

**frontend code**

```
import { user } from '../Join/Joined'
import socketIO from "socket.io-client";
import "./chat.css";
// import sendlogo from '../../../images/sendlogo.jpeg'
import Messages from '../messages/Messages';
import ScrollToBottom  from "react-scroll-to-bottom";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4500/';
let socket ; 




const Chat = () => {

    const [id, setid] = useState('');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [endmsg, setendmsg] = useState([]);

    const send = ()=>{
        const message = document.getElementById('chatInput').value ;
        document.getElementById('chatInput').value = "";
        socket.emit('message',{message,id})
        
    }

    
 socket = socketIO(ENDPOINT,{transports:['websocket']});

useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on('connect',()=>{
        // alert('connected');
        setid(socket.id);
        console.log('we are at the client side');
    })

    socket.emit('joined',{user});

    socket.on('Welcome',(data)=>{
        setMessages(currentMessages => [...currentMessages, data]);
        console.log(data.user , data.message);
    })

    socket.on('userjoined',(data)=>{
        setMessages(currentMessages => [...currentMessages, data]);
        console.log(data.user,data.message);
    })


    socket.on('leave',(data)=>{
    setMessages(messages => ([...messages,data]));
        console.log(data.user,data.message);
    })
    console.log(messages);



    return ()=>{

        socket.emit('disconnect');
        socket.off();

    }
},[])

useEffect(() => {

    socket.on('sendmessage',(data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        setMessages(currentMessages => [...currentMessages, data]);
        console.log(data.user,data.message,data.id);

    })

  return () => {
    socket.off();

  }
}, [])




  return (
    <div className='chatPage'>
        <div className='chatContainer'>
            <div className='header'>
                <h2>Chat-ting</h2>
                <a href='/'><button className='btnclose' type="button">X</button></a>
                <span className='headname'>Hello , {user}</span>
            </div>
            <ScrollToBottom  className='chatBox'>
                {messages.map((item,i)=> <Messages user={item.id===id?'':item.user} message={item.message} cls={item.id===id?'right':'left'} />)}                
            </ScrollToBottom >
            <div className='inputBox'>
                <input onKeyDown={(event)=> event.key === 'Enter' ? send() : null} type='text' id='chatInput' />
                <button onClick={send} className='sendBtn'>send</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div className='footer'>This website is in Development Phase . Stay tuned for updates.For any suggestion Mail: <a href='vaibhavbhatt9666@gmail.com'>vaibhavbhatt9666@gmail.com</a></div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Chat
```

**backened code**

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const { log } = require('console');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const users = {};

app.use(cors());

const io = socketIO(server);
port = 4500 || process.env.PORT ;

io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    console.log("new connection");

    socket.on('joined',({user})=>{
        users[socket.id] = user;
        console.log(users);
        console.log(`${user} has joined`);
        socket.broadcast.emit('userjoined',{user:"Admin",message:` ${users[socket.id]} has joined`});
        socket.emit('Welcome',{user:"Admin : ",message:"Welcome To The Chat "})

    })

    socket.on('message',({message,id})=>{
        console.log(message," ",id);
        console.log(users[socket.id]);
        io.emit('sendmessage' ,{user:users[id],message,id});
    })

    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        if(users[socket.id]){
            socket.broadcast.emit('leave' , {user:"Admin", message:`${users[socket.id]} has left`})
        }
        else{
            delete users[socket.id];
        }
        
        console.log(`${users[socket.id]} Left `);
    })


})

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("working node.js server")
})

server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server is working");
})
```

**jason for frontened**

```
{
  "name": "chatting_application",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.2",
    "react-scroll-to-bottom": "^4.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

**jason for backened**

```
{
  "name": "serverstat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: first put this line `socket = socketIO(ENDPOINT,{transports:['websocket']})` inside useEffect or outside app component. and second in backend please use `port = process.env.PORT || 4500`. then check it is working or not

Comment: it is still not working i did as you said ... and committed the result too. and i guess it is producing multiple websockets with no data is being send

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what your exact issue is, however I do see some things that I would do differently. I'll go ahead and post how I would do it, and maybe it will work for you.

Firstly, the [Socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/) for v4.x use ES modules, and the default export is not `Server`. I would change this to ES Module syntax (import) if you can. I'm not familiar with using `require` with socket.io.

Secondly, you aren't using `new` when creating the socket instance.

Thirdly, using `http.createServer(app)` is not necessary in this case. Using `app.listen()` returns a server instance you can use so create your websocket.

**Backend Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
import { Server } from 'socket.io'; 

const users = {};
const port = process.env.PORT || 4500;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());


app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("working node.js server")
})

const server = app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server is working");
})


const io = new Server(server);


io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    console.log("new connection");

    socket.on('joined',({user})=>{
        users[socket.id] = user;
        console.log(users);
        console.log(`${user} has joined`);
        socket.broadcast.emit('userjoined',{user:"Admin",message:` ${users[socket.id]} has joined`});
        socket.emit('Welcome',{user:"Admin : ",message:"Welcome To The Chat "})

    })

    socket.on('message',({message,id})=>{
        console.log(message," ",id);
        console.log(users[socket.id]);
        io.emit('sendmessage' ,{user:users[id],message,id});
    })

    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        if(users[socket.id]){
            socket.broadcast.emit('leave' , {user:"Admin", message:`${users[socket.id]} has left`})
        }
        else{
            delete users[socket.id];
        }
        
        console.log(`${users[socket.id]} Left `);
    })
})
```

Next, for the frontend stuff again I would try to use `import` if you can. `io` is not the default export, so it would need to look like this:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
```

Also, I'm not sure what your specific setup is between your frontend and backend, but I have a suspicion that your real issue here is your `ENDPOINT` on the frontend.

When you create your socket from the server instance returned from `app.listen()` you can have your socket and your server listening on the same port, in which case your `ENDPOINT` can just be "/". This is super useful because you don't need to setup environment variables for if your port changes, etc.

Good luck, hopefully this helps.